# How to use eventlet library for async gunicorn workers

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, eventlet, green-threads

One of my django projects is deployed using **ansible (gunicorn & nginx)**. Below is **gunicorn** configuration :

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8001'
backlog = 2048

workers = 8
worker_class = 'sync'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 300
keepalive = 2

spew = False

daemon = False
pidfile = None
umask = 0
user = None
group = None
tmp_upload_dir = None

loglevel = 'info'
errorlog = '/var/log/error.log'
accesslog = '/var/log/access.log'

proc_name = None

def pre_fork(server, worker):
    pass

def pre_exec(server):
    server.log.info("Forked child, re-executing.")

def when_ready(server):
    server.log.info("Server is ready. Spawning workers")

def worker_int(worker):
    worker.log.info("worker received INT or QUIT signal")


    ## get traceback info
    import threading, sys, traceback
    id2name = dict([(th.ident, th.name) for th in threading.enumerate()])
    code = []
    for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
        code.append("\n# Thread: %s(%d)" % (id2name.get(threadId,""),
            threadId))
        for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):
            code.append('File: "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename,
                lineno, name))
            if line:
                code.append("  %s" % (line.strip()))
    worker.log.debug("\n".join(code))

def worker_abort(worker):
    worker.log.info("worker received SIGABRT signal")
```

The worker processes are running synchronously. I want them to run concurrently as I have a lot of requests per minute on this server. On research I got to find that I can use python libraries like `eventlet` which uses **greenthreads** for concurrency.For this I need to change the worker_class to eventlet as :

```
worker_class = eventlet
```

But now I am clueless. I don't get how to implement the asynchronous green threads for this project. May be this is a stupid question but I really need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can I get some insight here??? please...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've already done everything required. `worker_class = eventlet` or `gunicorn -k eventlet` is enough to run HTTP request handlers concurrently. And then you can serve many concurrent requests with sleep or IO in their handlers.

Answer (score 3):

first, you need install the package

```
pip install gunicorn[eventlet]
```

then, change the worker_class to eventlet